# What is the use case of the deferred security context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have been going through the Spring Security docs and been playing around with basic authentication projects. I am confused as to what is the use of deferred context in authentication?

I have gone through the [javadocs of the class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext.html) and tried to see the flow of authentication, but am unable to figure out its purpose.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/DeferredSecurityContext.html, this is the class I was referring to. I was trying to understand the flow of authentication and the purpose of this class. There is no mention of it in the spring docs specifically.

Answer (score 2):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10913) explains it best. To summarize:

> A benefit is that if it takes some work to obtain the SecurityContext, the(n) it is only looked up if necessary.
>
> For example, currently the `SecurityContext` is looked up from the `HttpSession` for every page. When using distributed sessions (i.e. `Spring Session` + `Redis`) this is a lot of unnecessary overhead for accessing public css, javascript, and images. With these changes Spring Security can avoid accessing the `HttpSession` for public resources like javascript, css, images, public html pages, etc.

`AuthorizationManager` may not need to access the `SecurityContext` to authenticate (e.g. public invocation was allowed), in this case having a `Supplier` helps to skip the work needed to obtain the `SecurityContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find the answer for this too. Apparently from what I understood , it is used to save and persist context between requests. For instance , when you have to persist context information (uesr roles , authority , authenticated status, etc.) between requests.

Seems like it's also brought as an alternative to the deprecated package called SecurityContextRepository. I think you would get a better idea if you read about that. Also refer [loadDefferedContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html#loadDeferredContext(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest))